# Putting "About us" context in Footer , is it valid from UX prospective?

Tags: usability, footers

I am making a web page for a local client, and he advised me to put an **about us** paragraph below to the company logo **in the footer section**. like this bellow image
[image]

I have seen these kinds of things on many pages, but the reality is, it already present on the landing page and a dedicated about us page, do we still need it in the footer?

> before writing this question I came through the [NNgroup blog](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/footers/). and
> there is no mention of the about us section in the footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Content SEO

> A homepage needs to have content, text content that search engines can read and understand.

<sub>*Read more about SEO here: [How to SEO your homepage](https://www.reliablesoft.net/how-to-seo-your-homepage/)*</sub>

The importance of placing corporate info text on the homepage is not due to practicality or aesthetics but because of SEO.

The text on a landing page or an "About Us" page does not have the same reading by search engines as the homepage. Your client is right .